# Sorting Multidimensional Array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

So I got a homework and I am currently stuck.

I need to do the following:

1. Create a static public method with name "flatternAndSortWithoutBiggest" which has a two-dimensional array and

returns a one-dimensional array.

The method should take the values from the two-dimensional array and copy it into a one-dimensional array.

While doing that, the biggest number of each array should be left out e.g. {{1,2,3},{4,6,5}} would return {1,2,4,5}

The array also needs to be sorted with the BubbleSort function. If an array is empty or null return an array of length 0.

```
public static int[] bubblesort(int[] arr) {
  boolean swapped;
  do {
    swapped = false;
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)        // This is only the BubbleSort code in case you 
                                                // are wondering what this sorting algorithm is.
      if (arr[i - 1] > arr[i]) {
        int swap = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[i - 1];
        arr[i - 1] = swap;
        swapped = true;
      }
    } while (swapped);

    return arr;
}
```

I Literally got no idea how to combine all those steps e.g. sorting, leaving out biggest number, copying into a one dimensional array.

Comment: So what is stopping you from iterating all arrays, then sorting each, then iterate again and copy over all elements into the 1D array except the last item (biggest) of each?

Comment: If you need help getting started, there's a blog post [here](http://www.patriciashanahan.com/beginner.html) with some pointers.

Comment: This question is too broad for SO. I suggest to read more tutorials and/or other articles for beginners. But as a hint, I suggest ...

Comment: ...to create several methods that only do one thing - one that sorts a one-dimensional array (maybe with bubble-sort) - one that cuts off the last element of a one-dimensional array - one that flattens a two-dimensional array to a one-dimensional one. If you have all those little helper methods, you can easily assemble them to the bigger function you need.

Comment: this is not place to have your Homework done. At least produce Something and if that doesn't work properly ask for help. The signature of your method doesn't match with requirements (you need to flat a int[][] and the methode signature take a int[]

Answer (score -1):

So, you laid out the general structure of what you need to do already. Sort the individual arrays, drop the largest number, then copy into a 1-dimensional array. If you aren't familiar with iterating through multi-dimensional arrays you can read more [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multidimensional-arrays-in-java/). If you combine that with the sorting function that you have provided then you will have all the tools you need to do your homework.

If you are looking for more specific help on getting something working then you'll need to provide a little more information on that.

Answer (score -1):

Don't get yourself jammed up by "multi-dimensional array."  It looks like you already understand what an array is.  You can have an array of ints, an array of Strings, you get those, right?  Well, you can also have an array of (array of ints).  That's all a two-dimensional array is, an array of arrays.